# OpenCL library is intalled but don't link while compiling

Tags: linux, linker, opencl

I'm having some trouble compiling a OpenCL aplication. When I run:

```
gcc -L/usr/include/CL -lOpenCL opencl-app.c -o out -lm
```

I receive the message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
```

The library exists, cause, when I run:

```
sudo find / -iname "*opencl*"
```

I receive :

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/opencl-headers_1.2-2013.10.23-1_all.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/opencl-headers.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/opencl-headers.list
/usr/include/CL/opencl.h
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/opencl-headers
/usr/share/doc/opencl-headers
/home/opuser/OpenCL
```

I'm including in the code this way:

```
#ifdef APPLE
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/opencl.h>
#endif
```

I'm Using ubuntu 14.04. What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `-v` flag?

Comment: "The library exists...." . How did you reach that conclusion? I see no library there

Comment: Have you only installed the OpenCL headers and not any implementation provided by the hardware vendors?